# Create a CSV file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, sql-server

I am trying to export data from a SQL server database to a CSV file using Powershell. I already have the script done and it's been tested and it works but just need a little patch done. If there is no data to export, I do not want a file created but currently it creates the file.

```
$ConnectionString = "Data Source=SQLInstance; Database=db; Trusted_Connection=True;";
$streamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter "\\servername\someFolder\Testing.csv"
$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnectionString
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConn
$sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM db..mytable where updated = 0"
$sqlConn.Open();
$reader = $sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

$array = @()
for ( $i = 0 ; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++ ) 
    { $array += @($i) }
$streamWriter.Write($reader.GetName(0))
for ( $i = 1; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i ++) 
{ $streamWriter.Write($("," + $reader.GetName($i))) }

$streamWriter.WriteLine("")
while ($reader.Read())
{
    $fieldCount = $reader.GetValues($array);

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length; $i++)
    {
        if ($array[$i].ToString().Contains(","))
        {
            $array[$i] = '"' + $array[$i].ToString() + '"';
        }
    }

    $newRow = [string]::Join(",", $array);

    $streamWriter.WriteLine($newRow)
}
$reader.Close();
$sqlConn.Close();
$streamWriter.Close();
```

I need to check if there is data before the file is created. Please help me, I am very new to PS.

Answer (score 0):

You're using PowerShell, no need to fuss about with .NET in most cases.

```
$ConnectionString = "Data Source=SQLInstance; Database=db; Trusted_Connection=True;";
$outfile = @()
$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnectionString
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConn
$sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM db..mytable where updated = 0"
$sqlConn.Open();
$reader = $sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
$array = @()
for ( $i = 0 ; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++ ) 
    { $array += @($i) }
$line = $reader.GetName(0)
for ( $i = 1; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i ++) 
{ $line += ($("," + $reader.GetName($i))) }

$outfile += $line
while ($reader.Read())
{
    $fieldCount = $reader.GetValues($array);

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length; $i++)
    {
        if ($array[$i].ToString().Contains(","))
        {
            $array[$i] = '"' + $array[$i].ToString() + '"';
        }
    }

    $outfile += [string]::Join(",", $array);
}

if ($outfile.Count -gt 0)
{ $outfile | Out-File "\\servername\someFolder\Testing.csv" }
```

Pretty straightforward, instead of writing directly to the file in each case (which requires the file to be created beforehand), save everything to an array `$outfile` then at the end, test if anything was added and if so write to file.